# C++ pointers to functions as param

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void passPointer(int *pointer)
{
    cout << *pointer;
}

int main()
{
    int *iNum = new int(25);

    passPointer(iNum);

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why when I use the `passPointer()` function in main, it has to be `passPointer(iNum)` but not `passPointer(*iNum)`? Is it because I am dereferencing it at the parameter if I use `*`? Please explain as detailed as you can as I am a bit confused.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very sympathetic to these sorts of questions, because this is one of the only things that I had trouble with when learning C++.

The basic problem is that in the syntax of C++, the `*` and `&` characters are used for many different things with similar but subtly different meanings.

In your case, you are considering using `*` in four different places.

In the first place: `int *iNum = new int(25);`, the `*` is sitting in a declaration. This means that is is a type annotation saying that `iNum` is a pointer.

In the second place: `passPointer(*iNum);`, the `*` is sitting in an *expression*. This means that it is the dereference operator, which means: "get the value pointed to by `iNum`". In this case the value pointed to by `iNum` is an `int`. As you will see later, `passPointer` is declared to take an argument of type `pointer to int`, so you cannot pass a plain `int` as an argument to `passPointer`. You should instead just pass `iNum` (as `iNum` *is* a pointer to int).

In the third place: `void passPointer(int *pointer)`, the `*` is again sitting in a declaration. This means that it has the same meaning as in the first place - it says that `pointer` is a pointer (to `int`).

In the fourth place: `cout << *pointer;`, the `*` is again sitting in an *expression*. This means that, as in the second case, it is saying "dereference `pointer` and get the value that `pointer` is storing the address of".

Answer (score 3):

It is because you have declared `passPointer` to take an argument of
type `int*`.  `iNum` has type `int*`, and so can be passed directly to
`passPointer`.  `*iNum` has type `int`, and there is no implicit
conversion of `int` to `int*`, so you can't pass it to `passPointer`.

More generally, in C++ (and in just about all other typed languages as
well), every expression and every variable has a type.  The type of an
expression is expressed in terms of the type of its operands: if the
type of the operand of a unary `*` is `T*` (and the type must be a
pointer), then the type of the results is `T`.  And to call a function,
you must provide the right number of arguments, with the right types.

Answer (score 1):

This creates variable of name `iNum` and type `int *`:

```
int *iNum = new int(25);
```

This accept parameter of type `int *`:

```
void passPointer(int *pointer)
```

This passes the parameter of name `iNum` and type `int *`:

```
passPointer(iNum);
```

No need to think of pointers, these are all data types. Think of pointers only when you do pointer arithmetics and referencing, referencing. ;)

`int****` is just a type.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because I am dereferencing it at the parameter if I use `*`?

Yes. `iNum` has type pointer to `int`, `*iNum` has type `int`. If you had a function that takes an `int`, then you could pass it `*iNum`.

Answer (score 0):

The `passPointer()` function takes a pointer-to-int. `iNum` is already a pointer-to-int, so you just pass it as-is. There is no need to deference it.